# Ajax PHP file uploader won't work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, upload, xmlhttprequest

I am working on ajax image uploader which work automaticly when somebody submit the image my problem is that it doesn't work as expected when i add rename to my code to order the name of the images

```
 rename("user_image/".$_FILES[uploaded][name].".png","user_image/".$_SESSION["id"].".png");
```

the file won't be uploaded and moved to the specified directory but when i remove it the file is uploaded i was thinking that the problem was from permission that he can edit files the file permission is 644

Here is my php file :

```
<?php
   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
          $file = $_FILES["uploaded"];
          $target_dir = "user_image/";
          $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploaded"]["name"]);
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploaded"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);
          rename('user_image/'.$_FILE["uploaded"]["name"].".gif",'user_image/'.$_SESSION["id"].".gif");
   }
?>
```

And this is the rest of html and ajax :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Register</title>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700|Ubuntu:300,400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="half1">
            <div id="upload">
               <div id="user">
                   <img src="/img/1.png" id="one" alt="User image"/>
               </div>
              <img src="/img/plus.png" alt="Upload">
              <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input name="uploaded" type="file" id="file_upload"/> </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="half2">
            <h1>Sign up!</h1>
            <form action="register.php" method="post" >
                <input type="text" placeholder="Age" name="age">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Favourite dish" name="dish">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="user_id" style="display:none;" ><?= $_SESSION["id"]; ?></p>
    <script charset="UTF-8">
        function _(id){
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }
        _("file_upload").onchange = function() {
            var id = _("user_id").innerHTML;
            var file = _("file_upload").files[0];
            var formdata = new FormData();
            formdata.append("uploaded",file);
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.onreadystatechange =
            function(){
                if(ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200){
                   _("one").remove();
                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                    var first_path = '/user_image/';
                    var path = first_path.concat(id,'.png');
                    img.setAttribute('alt','User image');
                    img.setAttribute('id','one');                        
                    img.setAttribute('src',path);
                    _("user").appendChild(img);  
                    alert("end");
                }    
                else{
                    _("one").remove();
                    var img = document.createElement('img');
                    img.setAttribute('src','/img/loading.gif');
                    img.setAttribute('alt','User image');
                    img.setAttribute('id','one');
                    _("user").appendChild(img);                        
                }
            }              
            ajax.open("POST","upload_image.php");
            ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data"); 
            ajax.send(formdata);
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I always read that you cannot pass files with Ajax due to it's content. May I'm wrong, but that is what I read when someone asked for it.

Comment: The uploaded file is actually stored with a temp file name. Use `$_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name']`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image upload ajax don't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617427/image-upload-ajax-dont-work)

Comment: I've answered the xhr problem just an hour ago. You need to add specific questions. You're repeating the upload problem and addressing moving a temporary file problem in this thread. Please ask separate questions.

Comment: Check the php.ini value for `file_uploads`. It should be set to `1`. It may be disabled, and that could prevent the user from uploading files.

Answer (score 2):

You want to `rename` something, what you cant. `$_FILE['uploaded']['name']` is the original file name of clients machine. So there will be no file like `C:\tmp\abc.png` on your server box, what means, you can not rename that.

Anyway, whats the point of this line of rename? If you want to rename it, do it in the `move_uploaded_file` function.

Comment: Even when i rename it on move_uploaded_file the file won't be uploaded

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not give static extension of image file when you rename a file and you do not change the extension of the image during file uploading.

Answer (score 1):

The content type header needs to be set to `multipart/form-data`. So the server knows what kind of data it is expecting.

This will work in Internet Explorer

```
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
```

But adding this in Firefox or Chrome results in losing post data in PHP.

Now the server knows that it can expect some complex form data including files and blobs.

Comment: I already specified the content encryption type in the tag encrypte = "multipart/form-data"

Comment: Mouser the same problem still exist even when i did exactly what you told me please help ?

Comment: what does PHP give back (try `var_dump` again). Have you sniffed your post with a dev tool? What gets send to the server?

Comment: I got an error in the sended response that uploaded is undefined index but as you can see in my code that i defined the name attribute in the input tag what should i do please help ?

Comment: Did you browser sniff the request via a `dev tool`? Is `uploaded` sent by the browser in the post arguments?

Comment: Please help the input tag has the attribute of name has the value of  "uploaded" but on the server response it seems like the server did not found it is there any way to reference an input with ajax during the sent of the request or something like that please help i spent more than 10 hours trying to make it work

Comment: @Maroxtn try renaming `uploaded` to `uploaded[]` when it's appended as formData

Comment: still the same error here is my html and php again please help ! : http://pastebin.com/bqKXxiAk php: http://pastebin.com/EGkzVjcE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67558/discussion-between-mouser-and-maroxtn).